# Check what version if any of jquery is loading

Tags: jquery

I have found several codes to check the version of jquery loaded. However, i'm looking for a step by step way to use that code so I may see the output. For instance, do I need to write html headers, body, and where to insert the code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This question is different. Let's assume that I know absolutely nothing about html or coding and just an average IT guy.

How do I create something that will give me the version of jquery?

Does it load in the browser and used for every website visited?

Is it loaded on the local PC?

Where can I find it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you would like to do .. By the way, what have you tried so far ?

Comment: `$.fn.jquery` gets you the jQuery version number.

Comment: I guess putting it at the end of body tag would be the safest in case jquery is loaded at the bottom of body

Comment: jQuery version is determined by what .js file is included by the webpage.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the bottom of the body of your page, and it should alert the current version of `jQuery` that's running.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (typeof jQuery !== 'undefined') {  
    alert(jQuery.fn.jquery);
}
</script>
```

`var ver = jQuery.fn.jquery` will give you the value in a variable. What you do with that information from there is up to you, as you've not stated what your intention is.